# Difference between "Wertung" and "Auswertung"

Tags: difference

What are the differences between *Wertung* and *Auswertung*?
Whenever we see *Aus-* as prefix, the meaning of stem word differs slightly with the prefixed word. But for these two words it seems to be the same meaning.

How to use them differently in sentences?

Comment: What difference between https://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&relink=on&sectHdr=on&spellToler=std&search=wertung and https://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&relink=on&sectHdr=on&spellToler=std&search=auswertung don't you understand?

Comment: @Robert: As *both* give "assessment" and "evaluation" (=40% overlap for "Wertung"), pointing to leo.org isn't necessarily hepful in this case...

Comment: @Stephie: I disagree. "Wertung" has 5 translations, "Auswertung" has 14. "evaluation" is the only one they have in common. That is 1 in 5 (20%) or 1 in 14 (7%). My point is that SyParth did not seem to have bothered to look these words up but rather tried to explain them from the Aus- prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Auswertung* means, literally, extracting a useful, significant result from a clutch of data:

> Die Auswertung der Daten des Flugschreibers ergab, dass der Höhenmesser des Flugkapitäns fehlerhaft gewesen war.
>
> Die Umfrage war nicht fachgerecht durchgeführt worden und wurde daher nicht ausgewertet.

*Wertung* basically means estimating the worth or merit of something or somebody:

> Eine wissenschaftliche Feststellung sollte per se keine moralische Wertung enthalten.
>
> Nach meiner subjektiven Wertung ist er als Vorsitzender untragbar geworden.

In sport, *Wertung* is the task of a jury, primarily:

> Die Wertungen des Punkterichters fielen auf, weil sie von denen seiner Kollegen stark abwichen.

As a derivative, *Wertung* can also mean *ranking*, mainly in sport:

> Sie fiel aus der Wertung, weil sie nicht zugelassene Schuhe getragen hatte.

*Bewertung* is somewhat between *Auswertung* and *Wertung*, as it combines the evaluation of a set of data (a personnel file, a figureskating program, etc.) with a subjective catalogue of values:

> Die Bewertung meiner Leistung durch die Punkterichter konnte ich nur als ungerecht empfinden.

Answer (score 4):

*Eine Auswertung von etwas* means *an analysis/evaluation of something*, whereas *eine Wertung von etwas* is more like *a rating/judgment/grading* (to name only characteristic examples).

> Die Auswertungen der Testergebnisse wurden am Montag in der Lokalzeitung publiziert.
>
> Die interne Auswertung kam zu dem Ergebnis, dass...
>
> Einer der Kampfrichter lag mit seiner Wertung völlig falsch.
>
> Trotz ihrer Fehlversuche ist sie immer noch in der Wertung.

Examples are from [wiktionary](http://de.m.wiktionary.org/).

Comment: Might be a good idea to connect the two nouns to the verbs *auswerten* and *(be)werten*. And maybe also add the connection between *Bewertung* and *Wertung*? Otherwise nice and short answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seems for me a similar distinction as between evaluation (very closely corresponding to "Auswertung") and valuation (weakly corresponding to "Wertung"). The first one is any sort of looking at numbers/material/statistics and drawing conclusions, while the second is determining the value of something or ranking.